# Htaccess that doesn't break wordpress and another application

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have recently purchased a system that I am trying to install. It is the Freelance Cockpit 3. It requires to modify htaccess if there is a 404 or 500 internal server error.

The story is:

- I have a wordpress site installed on the root directory which I am
  intending to use.
- I installed that purchased system and had to modify the .htaccess
  file
- The Wordpress site broke and the system worked.
- When I try to put the code for wordpress the in the .htaccess file,
  the other system breaks.

The regular wordpress code in the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The code for the system for the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
#Could be removed RewriteBase /crm1/
RewriteBase /app/
```

The wordpress is installed in www.mydomain.com/

The system, I made a subdirectory for which is clients.mydomain.com/app

Does anyone kindly know how to combine both to make this work? I am asking here because the dev is very busy.

Thank you,

Comment: A subdomain is a different website, a correctly configured setup would have no connection in terms of htaccess rewrite rules between the two.

Comment: put `RewriteBase` above the related Rewrite... directives

Comment: possible, you need additional host checking like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$`

Comment: Where are these two `.htaccess` files on the filesystem? (Presumably you are using two separate `.htaccess` files and not trying to combine into one?) And where does your `clients` subdomain point to? `.htaccess` files work along the file system path, regardless of the subdomain/hostname.